# lapply date format to many dataframes

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, lapply

I'm having difficulties cycling through a list and apply the same format to the same variable in many data frames:

```
df1 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1446336120, 1446336180, 
1446336240, 1446336300, 1446336360), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = "datetime")

df2 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1446336120, 1446336180, 
1446336240), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = "datetime")
```

I want to apply the same format to all dataframes:

```
df1$datetime <- format(df1$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df2$datetime <- format(df2$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I tried this:

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "df"))

lapply(seq_along(list_df),
       function(i) format(list_df[[i]]$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

but not sure how to assign it back to each dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your current approach is not far off, but you never make an assignment back to the data frame.  Add each data frame to a list and then use `lapply`:

```
lst <- list(df1, df2)
lapply(lst, function(x) {
    x$datetime <- format(x$datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return(x)
})
```

At this point you have a list of data frames in the format you want.  If you then later wanted to export each data frame to a CSV file, you could try this:

```
for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
    filename <- paste0("out", i, ".csv")
    write.csv(lst[[i]], file=filename)
}
```

Comment: So if I understand, the changes are applied to the content of the list, not the data frames. I need to export the data frames once the format is applied.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel I think I understands your doubts.  It is necessary to assign the update to the LHS which is the data frame.  It won't stick otherwise.  You need to make an assignment, otherwise you are just acting on a temporary variable.

Comment: Shouldn't the `x` be returned?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as I'm struggling with lists. This does what I need, however it only lives in the list. I guess I need to assign the element of the list back to a dataframe? The code that's supposed to follow is `write.table` to export each `df1` `df2` etc

Comment: Your data frames need to be in some sort of collection if you want to use an `apply` function.  What is the problem with just accessing each element of the list as you need it?

Comment: I suppose I'm not sure how to do that... How  can I export a CSV of each element of the list?

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel You can again iterate this list of data frames and then write each one out to a separate CSV file.  If you want to perhaps combine them, you could use `rbind`, assuming they all have the same columns.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong because because the date format is not applied to the element of `lst`. E.g. if I type `lst[[1]]` it displays the original format instead of the desired `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(list_df, function(x) x %>% 
      mutate(datetime=format(datetime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```